# gzip strange idle usage?

Tags: gzip

I've noticed last couple of nights my fans come on lightly as if the cpu was being used. Found the culprit is gzip, however no open files and pretty much nothing else to show. What could it be up to ?

In System Monitor, Only shows ... "Control Group: /system.slice/anacron.service"

It doesn't happen for long so hard to get any info.

I noticed recently Cups was making one of my cpu cores work at 100% turned out had to empty the cache and was ok. Thing is today I now have something making a fan work (actually can't tell which but is a fan noise) and cpu usage is very low.

Using System Monitor still leaves some guess work. Is there any way to trace something that may be at work ? In other words ... how can i find whats making my fans work ?

Comment: Telling us where your message comes from may help, but web pages can be gzip'd so a browser open can use gzip to decode web sourced pages, but are you talking about a desktop? a server? as currently you've provided little for us to provide much in response.

Comment: Or`sudo lsof -c gzip`

Answer (score 0):

For finding why a process is running, I recommend:

```
ps auxf | less -S
```

This will show you not only the process, what the exact command is, but also a tree style indentation that shows what other processes started it.

I'm going to make a blind guess here: probably anacron is rotating log files, and using GZIP to compress the old copies to save storage space.